# mmi code error code android

Tags: android

If I type a character like "," and press on the call button , I get the error dialog "Connection problem or invalid mmi code". Can someone tell me from where this dialog pop up comes in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular string you mention comes from the framework resources in frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/strings.xml for the 'mmiError' resource. The region you are probably interested in looking at is the internal telephony code in frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GsmMmiCode.java

You can find this kind of thing using 'git grep' and suitable regular expressions.

I should add that this ends up back at the dialer application (packages/apps/Phone). If you have a look at PhoneUtils.java in that package there is a displayMMIComplete function that deals with the user display end of things.

Answer (score -1):

refrence site:coderanch (i read here!)

encode("#")
ussd = encodedHash + "456" + encodedHash